# Continuously control animation of rotation on View

Tags: java, android, animation, render, timertask

I have an app that needs to update the view `setRotation()` continuously based on my Cellphone Orientation data.

However, since this an easy and really simple app, I don't want to use `Canvas` nor `OpenGL` for that simple thing.

I wan't to use the System's views and only update the View let's say: every 20ms.

What is my best choice for the `renderer/updater`? Using a single `Thread` and calling `sleep(20)`. Or what?

Comment: You got some advance? See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Timer` with a `TimerTask` and

```
Timer temp = new Timer();
TimerTask task = ....;

temp.schedule(task, 0, 20000);
```

You can see one example in:

> http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/